# Quarkus Jandex index can not resolve artifact org.springframework:spring-web

Tags: spring-boot, maven, cdi, quarkus

I'm trying to migrate a spring boot application in Quarkus.
After some try I've find out that not all my beans are discovered, so I try to follow this guide and to create a jandex index https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference.
Except for the spring-web artifact all others dependecies has been discovered easily, but when it comes the time of spring-web it display:

**Could not resolve artifact org.springframework:spring-web:null**

The repository should be https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.28.RELEASE

Here's my application.yaml file.

```
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8998
  log:
    level: DEBUG
  index-dependency:
    bear-arch-rest:
      group-id: org.acme.bear
      artifact-id: bear-arch-rest
    bear-arch-core:
      group-id: org.acme.bear
      artifact-id: bear-arch-core
    bear-arch-exception:
      group-id: org.acme.bear
      artifact-id: bear-arch-exception
    spring-hateoas:
      group-id: org.springframework.hateoas
      artifact-id: spring-hateoas
    spring-web:
      group-id: org.springframework
      artifact-id: spring-web
```

Then when i try to build the project, it shows an error message with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.3.4.Final-redhat-00001:build (default) on project darwin-on-quarkus-rest: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.index.ApplicationArchiveBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve artifact org.springframework:spring-web:null. Please make sure it is present and contains a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. Note that artifacts that are part of the same project may not always be resolvable, in this case you should generate a META-INF/jandex.idx file instead using the Jandex Maven plugin.
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.index.ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.getIndexDependencyPaths(ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.java:148)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.index.ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.scanForOtherIndexes(ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.java:110)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.index.ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.build(ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.java:97)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:938)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:273)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve artifact org.springframework:spring-web:null. Please make sure it is present and contains a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. Note that artifacts that are part of the same project may not always be resolvable, in this case you should generate a META-INF/jandex.idx file instead using the Jandex Maven plugin.
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.index.ClassPathArtifactResolver.getArtifact(ClassPathArtifactResolver.java:68)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.index.ArtifactIndex.getPath(ArtifactIndex.java:14)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.index.ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.getIndexDependencyPaths(ApplicationArchiveBuildStep.java:136)
[ERROR]     ... 14 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I try to use a classifier but that didn't change anything.

When I try to delete the quarkus.index-dependency.spring-web property and I try to build then it shows:

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.3.4.Final-redhat-00001:build (default) @ darwin-on-quarkus-rest ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurerSupport: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurerSupport was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  05:45 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-03T14:30:48+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.3.4.Final-redhat-00001:build (default) on project darwin-on-quarkus-rest: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#registerBeans threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Producer method return type not found in index: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Types.getProducerMethodTypeClosure(Types.java:176)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.createProducerMethod(Beans.java:172)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.findBeans(BeanDeployment.java:763)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.registerBeans(BeanDeployment.java:206)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.registerBeans(BeanProcessor.java:122)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.registerBeans(ArcProcessor.java:262)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:938)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:273)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I received an answer from the quarkus support, you can find it there https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/Quarkus.20CDI.3A.20Spring-Web.20Artifact.20Could.20Not.20Be.20Resolved .

In a nutshell:

- You must use Quarkus Extensions for a list of compatible dependencies that you can find here https://quarkus.io/guides/#compatibility .
- If you already have a springboot application the only way to migrate to Quarkus is to change a very few code in order to adhere at the Quarkus's restrains
  Cheers