# "spring-boot-starter-web" compatibility with Quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, migration, quarkus

I'm new to Quarkus and I'm validating the migration viability of a quite complex Spring Boot application.

For now, I'm trying to make the first step into Quarkus world, which is to get the application running on Quarkus JVM (non native option) with as little changes as possible.

After dealing with "spring-orm", "spring-jdbc" and "spring-web" (client part) dependencies not covered by Quarkus spring extensions, now I'm facing the Quarkus build error below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:build (default) on project rules-engine-core: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#registerBeans threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Producer method return type not found in index: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean
```

After some research, I'm still lost about the truly right way to solve this problem that seems to be caused by code below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication( exclude = TransactionAutoConfiguration.class )
public class WebApplicationConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
    @Autowired
    private [ApplicationName]ExecutorSemaphoreValve semaphoreValve;

    // Replaces the need for web.xml
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean( ApplicationContext context ) {

        return new ServletRegistrationBean( new CXFServlet(), "/*" );
    }


    // Configure the embedded tomcat to use same settings as default standalone
    // tomcat deploy
    @Bean
    public AbstractServletWebServerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        // Made to match the context path when deploying to standalone tomcat-
        // can easily be kept in sync w/ properties
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory =
            new TomcatServletWebServerFactory( CorePropertyUtils.engineContext(), CorePropertyUtils.enginePort() );
        
        StuckThreadDetectionValve stuckThreadValve = new StuckThreadDetectionValve();
        
        semaphoreValve.setBlock( false );
        semaphoreValve.setFairness( false );
        
        factory.addContextValves( stuckThreadValve, semaphoreValve );
        
        return factory;
    }


    // Used when deploying to a standalone servlet container, i.e. tomcat
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application ) {

        return application.sources( Application.class );
    }
}
```

I've found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228985/quarkus-jandex-index-can-not-resolve-artifact-org-springframeworkspring-web), but it was result of lack of Quarkus spring extensions addition, which I believe is not my case.

It's just a matter of jandex indexation?

Do I need to change the code that uses the 'spring-boot-web' dependencies? (I hope not, at least for first migration stage)

Thanks a lot and best regards!

Comment: What does the code look like that causes this exception?

Comment: @geoand, I've posted an almost complete version of the code (removing the package, some application especific imports and with a little adjustment on a private field name), but I believe it will be sufficient for you analysis. Thanks a lot for your help! Once more...

Comment: This code taken from Spring Boot will not work on Quarkus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again @geoand! I was kind of expecting this response, but hopping to be wrong! I'm trying to adjust this "spring-boot" configuration now, with the same premises off all changes made so far, that is to have a project that could still be built to "spring-boot", but it's getting very difficult to keep it. Having that premise on mind, do you have any suggestion how to refactor this configuration? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I would personally start with what Quarkus offers out of the box with RESTEasy Reactive and Vert.x (no code required to set it up).